# IE 8-9 can't focus to iframe

Tags: javascript

Hello I getting not visible IFrame in IE I try print it, but IE return error what focus() method not identified. Why I get it? I remember that some days ago it wored

```
var iFrame = document.frames["printIfram"]; //document.frames.printIframe;
            iFrame.focus();
            iFrame.print();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a print function inside the Iframe to make it print itself on load:

At the bottom of the page, just use `window.print()`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `e` on the end of `printIframe`.

If that's just a typo, try `iFrame.contentWindow.focus()`.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem in ie8   and i thought it's a bug of ie
i tryed the accepted answer ,it haven't work yet;
nomatter where is the `window.print()`,it always print the parent page
so ,i give up the iframe,just open a new tab to print
have you got it work?